# How to display gridlines in ShinobiCharts

Tags: android, shinobi

I am using DateTimeAxis and NumberAxis for the X and Y Axis with ShinobiCharts.  LineSeries are being added successfully to the chart and displayed properly.  But the Gridlies which is mandatory for analysing the Series is not getting displayed and a blank background is being displayed.  Below is my Line Series code part :

```
LineSeriesStyle style = series2.getStyle();
        style.setFillStyle(FillStyle.GRADIENT);
        style.setAreaColor(Color.argb(179, 26, 96, 164));
        style.setAreaColorGradient(Color.argb(255, 26, 96, 164));
        style.setAreaColorBelowBaseline(Color.argb(179, 26, 96, 164));
        style.setAreaColorGradientBelowBaseline(Color.argb(255, 26, 96,
                164));
```

Please suggest me what changes I need to make with ShinobiCharts to get the Background gridlines to be displayed

Comment: Did you know that hellocharts-android is out? I use it myself and is awesome. Much faster than Shinobicharts. It is under Apache license. Can be customised to as we please. I just love it. Showing gridlines is a snap. Just call axisY.setHasLines(hasLines);

Answer (score 2):

Gridlines and stripes are not supported in V1.1 of Shinobi Charts for Android. However, V1.2 does include them and is due out very soon (it's just going through QA). Your code will look something like this:

```
        chart.getXAxis().getStyle().getGridlineStyle().setGridlinesShown(true);
```

Comment: Hey I am trying to use the set grid lines shown on the latest shinobi chart and the grid lines are still not appearing any ideas ?